# changing size of image and cell in QtableView depending on area available in fullscreen

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, qtableview, qtablewidget

How do I utilize the area of the screen available for a fullscreen opening `QTableView` so that thumbnail size can get bigger if the areas available , i.e. the number of rows will go down proportionally, right now I am doing like this

```
class MyTableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    """docstring for MyTableView"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTableView, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Widget | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint)
        sw = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(self).width()
        sh = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(self).height()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, sw, sh)
        self.showFullScreen()

        thumbWidth = 300
        thumbheight = 420
        col = sw/thumbWidth
```

the col = sw/thumbWidth defines the number of column , however If the screen area is empty then how do I increase the thumbnail width and which will intern lower the number of rows as well as column?

Answer (score 0):

I think these code may help you. I think QTableView is similar to QTableWidget.

```
    tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(6,8)
    hHeader = tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
    hHeader.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
    vHeader = tableWidget.verticalHeader() 
    vHeader.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
    self.setCentralWidget(tableWidget)
```